# Uniqueness of identity element

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a finite set and $e: \mathcal{G}\times \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ be a function such that

1. For all $a,c\in \mathcal{G}$, there exists a unique $b$ such that $e(a,b) = c$.
2. For all $b, c \in \mathcal{G}$, there exists a unique $a$ such that $e(a,b) = c$.

My hunch is that $\mathcal{G}$ is isomorphic to addition modulo $|\mathcal{G}|$, so I started checking if the pair $(G,e)$ forms a group. (The function properties are motivated by encoder-decoder systems.)

Right now, I want to know if $(G,e)$ has an identity. For a fixed $a\in \mathcal{G}$, the definition of $e$ implies that there exist two unique elements $0_L,0_R$ such that

- $e(a, 0_R)=a$
- $e(0_L, a)=a$.

My question is: how do I prove (or disprove) that $0_L=0_R$?

Comment: This may not be addition modulo $\vert\mathcal{G}\vert$ since every group operation satisfies this property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hunch is sadly, not correct.
Consider $\cal G = \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ and $e(a, b) := a-b$.
Then, the axioms you've mentioned are satisfied but your results clearly do not follow. (The operation does not even have an identity.)

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out correctly, we would need $|n| > 2$ with $n$ being an integer, of course! ($n = 0$ would give an infinite $\cal G$.)

Comment: provided $n>2$ ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: wow, I was considering adding a "funny" edit: "of course, $n$ is an integer not in $\{0, 1, -1\}$" but thought that it would be too unnecessarily pedantic!

Comment: Ouch. I was reading a proof where it was supposed to assume that the encoder had such properties, but actually started assuming that the encoder adds the message and the key modulo the alphabet size. I guess I am missing additional properties of the encoder.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani By leaving that out, you gave me the opportunity for an unnecessarily pedantic (and intendedly funny) comment

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I just realised that even in my original thought, I missed out on $n \in \{\pm 2\}$. Upon realising this, I see that maybe your comment wasn't so unnecessary after all. Thanks!